# Redirect to app with intent parameters passed Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, html, xamarin

at the moment I've implemented an intent for my android app.

I've added this dataattribute above my MainActivity class

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
DataScheme = "urlschemetest2",
DataHost = "testurl.com")]
```

On my device I've clicked on an a tag element below which then opened my app.

```
<a href="urlschemetest2://testurl.com">Test Opening App</a>
```

This works well, but my goal now is to also pass parameters so the application can handle the intent.

```
<a href="urlschemetest2://testurl.com/?firstname=john&lastname=doe">Test Opening App</a>
```

This code below is how I capture current intents (Push Notifications)

```
protected async override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    var data = intent.Data; // this returns testurl.com/?firstname=john&lastname=doe

    App.Firstname= intent.GetStringExtra("firstname");           
    App.Lastname= intent.GetStringExtra("lastname");
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
}
```

When my app opens via push notifications, the code above works flawlessly. When my app opens via URL, the code above returns null.

I know I can use the intent.Data and via some string manipulation I can grab firstname and lastname. But I was wondering if there's a better approach for grabbing parameters via intent.

Comment: does it work now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete URL Scheme protocol format consists of Scheme, host, port, path, and query. The structure is as follows:

```
<scheme>://<host>:<port>/<path>?<query>
```

and receive data in the called Activity :

```
Android.Net.Uri uri  = Intent.Data;
if(uri != null)
  {
    string firstName = uri.GetQueryParameter("firstname");
    string lastName = uri.GetQueryParameter("lastname");
  }
```